# How to get the perimeter of the circular sector in the figure?

Tags: geometry

I have a perimeter exercise of a circular sector, but my result is different. Where have I been wrong?

The exercise is:

[image]

With the formula: $\frac{\angle{O}}{360}2\pi r + 2r$

I have the circular sector of the biggest circle is equal to $4\pi + 16$ and the smallest is equal to $3\pi + 12$,  then i substract and i get $\pi + 4$.

But according to the guide, must be equal to $7\pi + 4$, what is wrong?

Comment: `4π+16` Where does the `+16` come from? `then i substract` Why *subtract* perimeters?

Comment: The +16 is from the formula of sector circular, and i substract to get the shaded area

Comment: `substract to get the shaded area` The question is about perimeter, *not* area. Subtracting those two perimeters gives you nothing meaningful in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circumference $C$ of a circle of radius $r$ is given by $C=2\pi r$

The sector of said circle with a central angle $\alpha$ has an arc length of $\frac{\alpha C}{360}$

Thus the arc length of the circles is given by $\frac{2\pi r\alpha}{360}$

$\alpha=90$ is fixed here as the angle is right, then we have $r=8$ for the outer circle and $r=6$ for the inner circle.

So the arc length of the outer circle is $\frac{1440\pi}{360}=4\pi$ and of the inner circle is $\frac{1080\pi}{360}=3\pi$.

The perimeter is these two arc lengths plus twice the difference of the two radii (which is $8-6=2$ - see your diagram for where these come from), and so the total perimeter is $4\pi+3\pi+4=7\pi+4$.

Let me know if any of this doesn't make sense

Comment: I do not understand, it is assumed that the large circle of radius 8 already contains the circle of 6, that is why he subtracted it.

Comment: Yes, but in the perimeter you are required to find, the 6cm is not included.

Comment: yes i already understand, thanks!